# “Statues carved in a row”

Tags: passive-voice, adverb-position, adverbials

Overseas ESL students were asked to transform a sentence into passive voice. One gave an unexpected answer, and their teacher consulted with me.

> **Original:** The people of Rapa Nui carved huge statues of heads ***all in a row***.

> **Expected Answer:** Huge statues of heads ***all in a row*** were carved by the people of Rapa Nui.

> **Student Answer:** Huge statues of heads were carved by the people of Rapa Nui ***all in a row***.

**Main question:** Is that the appropriate place for "all in a row"?

The student's answer struck me as natural enough, but I didn't know if it was grammatical or idiomatic.

The first question I have is whether "all in a row" is an adverbial phrase modifying "carved", as that's how the student seemed to interpret it. The teacher's point of view is that it's an adjectival phrase modifying "huge statues of heads". In my view, there's enough ambiguity that both interpretations can be correct. Am I right in my assessment so far?

My mind is bending around whether the statues were physically arranged in a row before being carved or after, but I feel like that might be off-track. At any rate, the final position seems like the only home for "all in a row" in the adverbial sense as "carved ***all in a row*** huge statues of heads" doesn't sound right.

*Edit: Actually, "Huge statues of heads were carved all in a row by the people of Rapa Nui" also seems acceptable.*

I did find a related StackExchange question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37601/passive-sentences-placing-an-adverbial-before-or-after-the-agent. There it was concluded that the adverbial "at school" could be placed after the verb or after the agent depending on emphasis:

> This homework was done by Vasya ***at school***.

> This homework was done ***at school*** by Vasya.

The active voice here would be structurally similar to our original, "Vasya did this homework ***at school***." However, "This homework ***at school*** was done by Vasya" doesn't sound right. That's why I opened this new question, as I don't think our sentences parallel each other completely.

Comment: Try it like this... **Active**: *The people of Rapa Nui carved huge statues of heads [that were] all in a row.* **Passive**: *Huge statues of heads [that were] all in a row were carved by the people of Rapa Nui.* Unless the people were all in a row, this one doesn't work: *Huge statues of heads were carved by the people of Rapa Nui [who were] all in a row.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Nice rationalisation, but the language doesn’t work that way. The student’s sentence is perfectly fine.

Comment: There are several different syntactic parses of the student’s sentence (and the original) all of which are grammatical. One might be where the sentence involves Extraposition from Noun Phrase movement (henceforth ENP). This is when a modifier that would normally occur just after the head noun in a noun phrase gets shunted to the end of the clause. Compare “That woman called that you met yesterday” (ENP),  and “That woman that you met yesterday called”  (No ENP). Another possibility is that *all in a row* is a depictive adjunct like *raw* in the following:

Comment: “He ate the pizza raw” / “The pizza was eaten raw”.

Comment: The trouble with the sentence with "all in a row" at the end is that it is ambiguous. It _could_ mean that the statues were all in a row but could also mean that the _people_ were all in a row when they were carving the statues.

Comment: @BoldBen There's a third possibility, that "all in a row" modifies "carved".

Comment: @BoldBen Agreed, which I suppose allows for more than one correct answer. If I were the book's publisher, I might favor something like, *"The people of Rapa Nui carved **and lined up** huge statues of heads throughout their island."*